# Bias-variance tradeoff in non-MSE setting

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, mean-square-error

In Casella & Berger, the derivation of Bias-Variance tradeoff assumes that the error in parameter inference is measured with Mean Squared Error. Given an estimator $W$ of $\theta$, MSE can be decomposed as:

$E_\theta\big[(W - \theta)^2\big]= Var_\theta(W) + \big(E_\theta W - \theta\big)^2$

where the first term is the variance of the estimator and the right term is the bias.

The same presentation is pretty much given in any book, e.g. Elements of Statistical Learning. Except that the error term also appears.

**But what if the assumption of MSE is violated? Can any type of error be decomposed into some function of (Variance, Bias)?**

**In particular, what about Mean Absolute Error or Median absolute error?**

**If not, then is it "illegal" to talk about Bias-Variance tradeoff with the loss function not corresponding to MSE?**

Comment: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1022899518027

Comment: @John: your statement is wrong. Check well on Casella Berger, (7.3.1) on page 330, LHS must be squared

Comment: If you do not use MSE, then you are likely to lose nice equalities.  For example you usually have $E_\theta\big[|W - \theta|\big] \not= E_\theta\big[|W - E_\theta W |\big] + \big|E_\theta W - \theta\big|$ though you may still find the $W$ which minimises $E_\theta\big[|W - \theta|\big]$ and this may not be when  $E_\theta W = \theta$.